# Running j on Chrome OS

Tags: chroot, j, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to run jconsole on Chrome OS. In both the chroot of Ubuntu that I have installed, and the normal Chrome OS shell, I receive the following error on both the 32- and 64-bit versions:

```
-bash: ./jconsole: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm not the best with UNIX systems, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out why I can't run this on either Chrome OS or the ubuntu chroot.

Comment: Do you prepend an accidental second dot? (`. ./jconsole`). What does `file jconsole` tells you?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can claim credit for this answer, but Eric Iverson recently suggested on the J forums that the best way to do this was to install a J server on a Unix server and then use a browser to access the server using the JHS frontend (works in any modern browser). It does require extra equipment and I expect that you had hoped that there was a version of J that would work in the Chrome OS, but when one of the developers of the language says run a browser in the Chrome OS and point it at a unix server running the J engine, I'd try that if you have not already.

Reference in J general forum: http://jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2014-June/036169.html

Answer (score 0):

## Short version

If you already installed successfully hopefully it's just a syntax error:

- `jconsole` instead of `./jconsole`

## Long version

*IMPORTANT:* You have to be in the chroot to run any regular Linux programs. The Chrome OS shell (crosh) doesn't allow installing anything as far as I know.

I'm on Chrome OS, using a chroot via [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) and playing with [j801](http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j801/), including `jconsole`.

Since I have a 1st-gen Samsung ARM Chromebook, I downloaded the [armhf version](http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j801/j801_armhf.deb). If you're using an Intel-based device, pick something else, maybe [linux32](http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j801/j801_linux32.tar.gz)

- use `dpkg -i j801_armhf.deb` to install to `~/j801`
- (optional but recommended) make a symlink `/usr/bin/jc -> /path/to/j801/bin/jconsole` to easily start jconsole from any directory.

See the [installation instructions](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/System/Installation/J801) for more detail.